# horizontal scrolling for list of images

Tags: java, android

I have tried to make a Horizontal scrolling of list of 5 images in my app.I wrote the following XML in my app. The problem that i am facing is it leaves a blank
area to the left and right of the screen ,i.e is blamk area before the image list starts and some blank area after the image list .

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/people" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/people" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/people" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/people" />
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Can anyone Help me how to remove this unwanted blank area ?
[image]
I tried NagarjunaReddy suggestion, but I got the result as shown in screenshot below.

Comment: just remove  `android:paddingRight="20dp"`

Comment: i guess my question is unclear....Lemme Rephrase..... I am not talking about the blank area in between the images .This blank area comes in the starting of the list of images and at the end of the list of the images

Comment: this is because you are giving android:layout_gravity="center" this attribute ..... thats y there is a blank area on the right n left side of linearlayout.

Comment: remove `android:layout_gravity="center"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` and try may be working not sure.

Comment: @NipunGogia i tried this too .still getting the same space

Comment: @sonia can you post screen shots if possible and mark red circle on your problem

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to my question .Actually this blank space is coming because of my mobile system operating system android versin 4.0. I checked my same app in android ver2.3 there i dint get any blank space anyways.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841576/app-loads-the-pdf-file-from-res-raw-pdf-file/13853863#13853863 ..... here is the link just refer my answer hope it will help u... :)

Comment: @NipunGogia okay . one thing i forgot to tell u that pdf file reading occurs with in the android app .i want something like this http://code.google.com/p/mupdf/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24359/discussion-between-sonia-and-nipun-gogia)

Answer (score 0):

try this remove pading for all imageviews `android:paddingRight="20dp"`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"          
        android:src="@drawable/people" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:src="@drawable/people" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:src="@drawable/people" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
        android:src="@drawable/people" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:paddingRight="20dp"` for all the `<ImageView>`s

Comment: ok now i understood your question. Remove android:layout_gravity="center" in <HorizontalScrollView>

Answer (score 0):

It should have nothing to do with the OS version.
Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/people" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/people" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/people" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/people" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You should get something like this:
[image: From the Graphical Layout editor]